# Using a Main program to edit all program headers in a directory?

Tags: sas

I have frequently encountered the following issue in my day to day programming at the office where files can be reused from one project to the next, but the header information needs to be updated for each file, when you are dealing with hundreds of files updating them all manually is a pain, and a waste of resources.

Ideally what I would like is a program that contains a standard header with attributes like author, project code, creation date etc, that I can manually update and when executed it will add this information to all the files/programs in a directory. We use a standard header, which cover the first 20 lines of each program and each attribute is on a certain line, or can be searched for in order to replace it.

For the most part I would like to develop this myself, but any starting point as to how to apply said header to the first 20 lines of each program and how to apply it to each file in a  directory. I want to add other functionality later for tracking purposes etc, but for now any help in getting started would be awesome.

Comment: Thanks you for the quick replies and for good tips.

Comment: Unfortunately using the include function is not an option as each of the programs needs to be a stand alone program, and that the header is not a general header but program specific, hence the only parts that I would want to change would be the Author/Date, directory path, sponsor. protocol, and the description of the program which I can pull in from a separate excel spreadsheet that we use for tracking purposes.

The assumption made by Quentin below "If the assumption is that you will have to manually type something into a header for every program for every project" is what I have to do.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big fan of using keyboard macros to generate header shells.  So when I hit CTRL-H, I get a header block comment with the sort of information you described, including my name and today's date.  If the assumption is that you will have to manually type *something* into a header for every program for every project (e.g. a revision note or whatever), then automatically adding 100 header shells doesn't save you much more than the keyboard macro approach.

That said, yes, you could do it with SAS using file statement or whatever.  Could probably do it with any good text editor.

And of course a better solution would be to get a version control system.

Comment: If possible can you please post such a keyboard macro?

Comment: I know it is not an ideal solution as I would still need to open each program and apply the change, but it is a start, and will still be a lot quicker than what I currently have to do.

Comment: Don't have one to post but if you search lexjansen.com for keyboard macro or abbreviation, should get plenty of hits, including  http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi28/108-28.pdf

Comment: +1 for 'get a version control system'.  The keyboard macro also seems like a reasonable alternative.  If you want to change all of that without touching the program at all, I think that's just not a good way to go; having a program automatically change your programs without any sort of QA is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't modify the programs in the directory this way, but rather use `%include` files.  We've done that on projects before, where you have a single program that includes libnames and such, and then you have

```
%include('header.sas');
```

or whatever in every program you write in that project.  Modifying the code programmatically like this is a bad idea, both because you might not have the most up to date version of the headers, and because it risks damaging the programs if you do it incorrectly).  Putting it as an include is easy, avoids replicating the same code 20 times (with possibility of error), and guarantees up-to-date code.

In your case, you can modify the 'header' file for the new day, and assuming you've set things up properly (which it sounds like you have), then the 100 or whatever other programs all can stay the same, unchanged, just including the updated header (automatically).  This has the added advantage that you don't make lots of tiny changes to the programs, meaning you know when a meaningful update to the program occurred (as opposed to just a daily run).

In general, this modular approach is superior - divorcing the 'individual  run' part of a program/process from the main part - because  of these reasons, and because it makes it easier to reuse programs for other purposes as well if you have it set up so the module is already prepared and just needs a header file in the same directory to automatically run.  (You can get the name of the current program and its path; if you need that, comment with what mode you use - batch or interactive - and what OS you are in).

This is also one of the places where the Enterprise Guide model is a bit better; there you have all of your project-related files in one project file (.egp), so you don't have to do even this - the project itself can have an autoexec process flow (which runs first, to set libnames and such) and can have notes/author/etc.

Comment: I read this question as being about a standard comment block to document each program, not standard code to be executed.  I think %include works well for the later, not sure it would be much help in this case, assuming he wants a separate comment block for each program, listing revision history etc.

Comment: Unfortunately with the environment that I work in we are unable to utilize a modular approach, and we only use Base SAS.

Comment: For my environment the best solution would be something alone the lines of a *.bat file that I would be able to run once at project start-up that would apply the specified fields author/date/sponsor/protocol/directory path to each program in the folder. This way it will edit all the files only once and then allow me to go and make updates to each program for the new project.

Comment: I'd reconsider your programming environment, then.  Programming this way is a pretty slow and error-prone way to do things.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. If a line starts with "Author:" it replaces the line with "Author: ME, ONLY ME!!!".
If you are on Windows, change all the forward slashes ("/") to backward slashes ("\").

```
%let infolder=/folder/where/sas/programs/are;
%let outfolder=/folder/where/new/sas/programs/are/going;
filename dummy temp;
data _null_;
  attrib currentinfile currentoutfile length=$32000;
  infile "&infolder/*.sas" filename=currentinfile lrecl=32000;
  input;
  currentoutfile="&outfolder./"!!scan(currentinfile,-1,"/");
  file dummy filevar=currentoutfile lrecl=32000;
  if index(_infile_,"Author:")=1 then put "Author: ME, ONLY ME!!!";
  else put _infile_;
run;
```